# A reasoning starting from an ordinary differential equation: what is the meaning?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, finance

I quote *Life Insurance Mathematics* (Gerber, 1997).

---

Let us consider a fund such that the initial capital $F_0$ is invested and at the end of year $k$ an additional amount of $r_k$ is invested, for $k=1,\dots,n$.

Assume that payments are made continously with an annual instantaneous rate of payment of $r(t)$, with $t$ denoting time. Thus the amount deposited to the fund during the infinitesimal time interval from $t$ to $t+dt$ is $r(t)dt$. Let $F(t)$ denote the balance of the fund at time $t$. We assume that interest is credited continously, according to a, possibly time-dependent, force of interest $\delta(t)$, with $\delta(t)$ consisting in:
\begin{equation}
\delta(t)=\lim_{m\to\infty}i^{(m)}=\lim_{m\to\infty}m\left[(1+i)^{\frac{1}{m}}-1\right]=\ln(1+i)\tag{1}
\end{equation}
with $i$ denoting an effective annual interest rate.

Interest credited in the infinitesimal time interval from $t$ to $t+dt$ is $F(t)\delta(t)dt$. The total increase in the capital during this interval is thus:
\begin{equation}
dF(t)=F(t)\delta(t)dt+r(t)dt\tag{2}
\end{equation}
To solve the corresponding differential equation:
\begin{equation}
F^{'}(t)=F(t)\delta(t)+r(t)\tag{3}
\end{equation}
$\color{red}{\text{we write:}}$
\begin{equation}
\color{red}{\frac{d}{dt}\left[e^{-\int_{0}^{t}\delta(s)ds}F(t)\right]=e^{-\int_{0}^{t}\delta(s)ds}r(t)\tag{4}}
\end{equation}
$\color{red}{\text{Integration with respect to }t \text{ from } 0 \text{ to } h \text{ gives:}}$
\begin{equation}
\color{red}{e^{-\int_{0}^{h}\delta(s)ds}F(h)-F(0)=\int_{0}^h e^{-\int_0^t\delta(s)ds}r(t)dt\tag{5}}
\end{equation}
$\color{red}{\text{Thus, the value at time }0 \text{ of a payment to be made at time }t\text{ is obtained by multiplication }}$
$\color{red}{\text{with the factor:}}$
\begin{equation}
\color{red}{e^{-\int_0^t\delta(s)ds}\tag{6}}
\end{equation}

---

---

Could you please help me understand all the passages underlying the reasoning in $\color{red}{\text{red}}$ above? (i.e. the logic behind them and the main mathematics passages)

Comment: This is the integrating factor method of solving first order, linear, ordinary differential equations.  The wikipedia [description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor#Solving_first_order_linear_ordinary_differential_equations) seems adequate.  Do you have further questions after reading that section of the article?

Comment: I guess I have understood the logic underlying the integrating factor method. However, in this specific case, I cannot really understand why one is allowed to write the equation $\color{red}{(4)}$. Could you please give me some hint to understand that? @EricTowers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This is a response to the question hidden in comments instead of present in the Question.  This would be a comment, but it is too long to fit in a comment.)

\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dt}&\left[e^{-\int_{0}^{t}\delta(s)ds}F(t)\right]  \\
    &= \frac{d}{dt}\left[e^{-\int_{0}^{t}\delta(s)ds}\right]  F(t)+ e^{-\int_{0}^{t}\delta(s)ds}\frac{d}{dt}\left[F(t)\right]  \\
    &= \frac{d}{dt}\left[e^{-\int_{0}^{t}\delta(s)ds}\right]  F(t)+ e^{-\int_{0}^{t}\delta(s)ds} F'(t)  \\
    &= e^{-\int_{0}^{t}\delta(s)ds} \frac{d}{dt}\left[{-\int_{0}^{t}\delta(s)ds}\right]  F(t)+ e^{-\int_{0}^{t}\delta(s)ds} F'(t)  \\
    &= -e^{-\int_{0}^{t}\delta(s)ds} \frac{d}{dt}\left[{\int_{0}^{t}\delta(s)ds}\right]  F(t)+ e^{-\int_{0}^{t}\delta(s)ds} F'(t)  \\
    &= -e^{-\int_{0}^{t}\delta(s)ds} \delta(t)  F(t)+ e^{-\int_{0}^{t}\delta(s)ds} F'(t)  \\
    &= -e^{-\int_{0}^{t}\delta(s)ds} \left( \delta(t)  F(t) - F'(t) \right)  \text{.}
\end{align*}
The above uses, in order, the [product rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule) for differentiation, the prime notation, the ([general](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule)) [exponential rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_rules#Derivatives_of_exponential_and_logarithmic_functions) for differentiation, the [constant multiple rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_rules#Differentiation_is_linear) for differentiation (and commutativity of multiplication), the [fundamental theorem of calculus (part 1)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#First_part), and distributivity of multiplication.

The result comes from (3) by moving $\delta(t)F(t)$ to the left-hand side, then multiplying both sides of this modified equation by the integrating factor to obtain (4).

Comment: Algebraically speaking, shouldn't the last line correspond to $-e^{-\int_0^t\delta(s)ds}(\delta(t)F(t)\color{red}{-}F^{'}(t))$? If not, why? @EricTowers

Comment: Of course.  However, replacing "to" with "in order to" is just pointlessly wordy.

Comment: Yeah, of course, but I just did it in order to be able to submit revision proposal (in fact, it is required to change at least $6$ characters)

Comment: @Strictly_increasing : I tend to use an HTML comment at the end for that purpose `<!-- This comment for minimal edit length purposes. -->`.

Comment: Thank you a lot for such an advice!